# How to Set a Property or Method Name as Number(int)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have this code

```
Public decimal Amt2016 { get; set; }
```

But i need to set it like below

```
Public decimal 2016 { get; set; }
```

I have tried and search in google, but i didn't get an actual answer, or is it possible to set two names for a property like that

```
[name="2016"]
Public decimal Amt2016 { get; set;}
```

Can anyone please help me to find out the solution?

Comment: Is it a class of model and represents a column in a database?

Comment: You should ask yourself why you need a property called `2016`. This is simply a number without any further meaning. However within your Xml or JSON or whatever what should 2016 stand for? I assume its some kind of temporal data, not just a number so you´d better be off call it `Data2016` or `Amt2016` as you already did.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, as it would cause ambiguous calls all over the place, the reason you can use text as a variable name at all is because it would need to be in speech marks to be seen as a string, this on the other hand can be seen as a number. Take this for example

```
int 2016 = 12345;
int multiplied = 3 * 2016;
```

What calculation would be done here if we could name variables as numbers? Would the sum be 3 * 12345 or 3 * 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start identifier name by number.

identifier-start-character:

- letter-character
- _(the underscore character U+005F)

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx) is more info.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the languages(As per my knowledge) doesn't allow to start identifier names with number or special characters except _(underscore) and so does .net. Simply you cannot do that.